# Show small window with image from CLI

Tags: c#

What the problem in this code i've written ?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class stfu {
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello Toxic world!");
        var f = new Form();
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        f.Controls.Add(new PictureBox() { ImageLocation = @"image.png",Dock = DockStyle.Fill});
        f.Show();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

form not responding. . .

Comment: The form can't be responsive when execution is stalled at Console.ReadLine().  Use Application.Run(f) instead.  There are more issues, trying to get a little pregnant is not a good idea.

Comment: Try `f.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need invoke Application.Run() method to properly process window's messages:

```
var f = new Form();
// init form here
Application.Run(f);
```